# SSL handshake exception with feign okhttp and jenkins

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, jenkins, junit4, spring-cloud-feign

Ssl handshake eception is coming while junits test cases are running in jenkins is building the maven project with command :-

```
mvn clean install
```

**Note**

1. All the test cases are running fine in local with same command.
2. Also the code is working fine when we have deployed the jar build in local on CF.
3. We are using self signed certificate in our project.

Please let me know what is going wrong here and what should be the workaround in this case.

Comment: If you are using an old Java version it may be the case that Maven tries to contanct an external repository that requires TLS1.2 or a cipher that uses AES256 and your Java version is too old and/or does not have the unlimited strength policy files installed that allow AES256 usage. My recommendation use at least a recent version of Java 8 as JRE/JDK for Maven. A recent free version of JDK8 can be found in in the [AdoptOpenJDK project](https://adoptopenjdk.net) (the recent versions from Oracle are no longer free!).

Comment: We are using Java 8 only for the project. My assumption is that while  building it on jenkins ,it is not able to find cacerts.jks which is our truststore file. This certificate is therein my local jdk . But don't know for sure.